# python skipping '\n' in the replace method

Tags: python, replace, newline

> The below json,this is from where I read data->

```
 [
    { 
    "Name":  "ABC",
    "state": "MA",
    "statements":   [
    "SET X=ABC",
    "USE @{Domain}",
    "Create table DEF"
    ],
    "parameters":
    [
    {"name": "Domanin", "required": true,  "description": "this is the domain name"}
    ]
    }
    ]
```

=======================================================================================

```
import re;
import sys;
import json;
loc_file=str(sys.argv[1])  ;
open_json=open(loc_file);
data=json.load(open_json);
list1=data[0].get('statements');
json_input_string="";
json_input_string=str(list1);
json_input_string=json_input_string.replace(r"Text ' ' followed by text",r"Text '\n'"); # This replace works fine but the replace below fails for '\n' 
f = open("Text.txt","w");
m=""
for c in list1:  
    #print "\n\n"+c
    m=str(c).replace(r"Text ' '",r"Text '\n'");  # Here it fails (does not preserve 'n')
    f.write(m+";\n")
```

> there are two possible things any of which will do either 
>   **Possible solution 1) :** 
>   if the replace method works inside loop
>   I am trying to do a replace at two
>   places, the replace function with the raw string notation works for
>   the above variable `json_input_string` but the same replace fails when
>   I try to do so inside the *loop of `list1`*.
>
> (list1 has data in the unicode format like this [u' set variable Text '
>   ' ',u'expression Text ' ' in table'] Moreover most of the python read
>   write functions I have tried so far fail when I need `'\n'` to be kept
>   in the replacement string.) 
>   OR 
>   **Possible Solution 2)** 
>   If the json_input_string can give me data in desired format
>    when i print json_input_string it gives me the output as below even though its type is 'str':

```
json_input_string=[u'SET X=ABC', u'USE @{Domain}', u"Create table DEF"]
```

> some have single quotes and some have double quotes. I want to convert
>   this string into an output without single/double quotes like this and
>   write to a file.

```
SET X=ABC;
USE @{Domain};
Create table DEF
```

Comment: Are you aware that the last line of your script prints `c` again and not `m` which hold the result of your `replace`?

Comment: sorry .i have updated the code ..that was typo..

Comment: Difficult to interpret this one. The only sample you show of what `list1` might be uses [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation), most likely unintentionally, and `'\n'` is an escape sequence for newline which you've disabled using raw literals. Please give us clear values (try using `repr`) of input data, manipulating code, produced result, and what you expected.

Comment: Hi yann i have updated the question to include all details

Comment: Still not seeing it. The word `Text` appears nowhere in your data, so neither replace operation can have any effect. Also confused about why your text is in weirdly formatted quote blocks and code has a semicolon infection.

Answer (score 0):

`m = str(c).replace(...)` the new string is in `m`, not `c`. Python strings are immutable.

Comment: sorry that was a typo .i have updated it in the code

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks a lot guys for the help .luckily i got the answer . I was
>   thinking ,because i don't see '\n' as text it is not there but it
>   just shifts to a new line so if i just change my replace method from

```
replace("LINES TERMINATED BY ' '","LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"); 
to 
replace("LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'","LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'");
```

> also you need to hold this replace inside a loop by assigning the replace value to a variable
>
> it works fine :).thanks for your efforts